# How to set scope property of NgDialog when using controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

Hi I have `StudentController` as follows,

```
function StudentController($scope,StudentService){
    $scope.student = StudentService. getStudent();

   $scope.editStudent = function(){
    return ngDialog.openConfirm({
                      template: 'edit-student.html',
                      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                      scope   : $scope // LINE 1
                });
   }
}
```

When `editStudent` function is invoked, I want to open a dialog to show edit option. And I want to use the `$scope.student` of `StudentController` itself in the `edit-student.html` as model data. for this feature, I can use `scope` property of NgDialog as `scope:$scope` (see LINE 1).

Now I am trying to change the `StudentController`  as suggested in the [Angular-StyleGuide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y032) where I am not going to use the `$scope` in `controller` at all. In that case, how can I access `student` in `edit-student.html`?

```
function StudentController(StudentService){
        var vm = this;
        vm .student = StudentService.getStudent();

        return ngDialog.openConfirm({
                          template: 'edit-student.html',
                          className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                          scope   : ???
                         // $scope is not used in this controller. 
                         //Then what should I send instead?
                         // I tried using scope :  vm . But it didn't work. 
                    });
        }
```

**Update** : updated with more details to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing it a bit. If you want to use controllerAs Syntax you need an own controller for the dialog.
e.g.

```
function StudentController(StudentService){
    var student = StudentService.getOne();
    return ngDialog.openConfirm({
                      template: template,
                      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                      controller: DialogController
                      controllerAs: 'vm',
                      resolve: {student: function() {return student; } }
                });
    }

    function DialogController(student) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.student = student;
    }
```

Comment: sorry if I didn't explain the question properly. I don't want to use a separate controller for the ngDialog. There is an option to set like `scope   :  $scope`. This option will work only when the current controller is injected with `$scope`. but when the current controller follows vm syntax, then how this` scope` property of `ngDialog` should be?

Comment: yeah then I misunderstood your question. I don't how to pass the scope in this case. But as you simply want to access the student you could pass it as resolve param. See my modified version.

Comment: You're saying to inherit parent scope on the ngDialog template you need to pass a resolve param with a function that returns the current scope var? One by one? Ew.

Comment: Also, doesn't this violate the Single Responsibility rule for Angular best practices? https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#single-responsibility

Answer (score 0):

I think you can omit it entirely.  This seems to be working for me.